# How can i get the parent_item_id on a simple product that's associated to a grouped product

Tags: magento

How can i get parent_item_id on a simple product ?
This give as result: Array

```
$simple_product_id = $_product->getId();

$grouped_product_ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($simple_product_id);


echo $grouped_product_ids
```

Answer (score 0):

Japs.

According to magento Methodology ,a simple can `be added  associated with multiple  Groups products.`Magento give result of this code `in array format`.

If your Simple Product is `associated with one group product`.then  getting group product id try below code

```
echo $grouped_product_ids[0]
```